# A deterministic algorithm for minimum cut of undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

Could someone name a few deterministic algorithm for minimum cut of undirected graph, along with their complexity please?
(By the way I learnt that there is a undirected version of Ford-Fulkerson algorithm by adding a opposing parallel edge for each directed edge, could someone tell me what is the time complexity of this one and maybe give me a bit more reference to read?)

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not entirely mistaken, the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm for a maximum flow can be used to also determine the minimum cut, based on the [Max-Flow-Min-Cut-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem), which is a special case of the LP duality theorem.

Comment: Where have you checked already?

Comment: @Codor

Yes finding the maximum flow is equivalent to finding the minimum cut. However Ford-Fulkerson is naturally applied to a network flow problem, which is represented a directed graph. A bit more work is needed to extended it to undirected graph, but I cannot find a good reference on this (if I can find some code it would be even more amazing)

Comment: To my understanding, it is sufficent to either split every non-directed edge into two directed edges or modify the algorithm to implicitly consider both edges.

Comment: @Codor
Um can I have some literature (and preferably also the code) on this if you have any？

Comment: @luk32uk
Sorry but I dont think I understood our question..

Comment: The textbook 'Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity' by Papadimitriou and Steiglitz covers the subjects in-depth.

Comment: Just set residual capacities for both directions and run any maxflow algorithm. E.g. FF is O(f*(n+m)), other algorithms even have strongly polynomial runtimes. In practice they are very fast if properly implemented

Comment: Of course if you're talking about general cut and not s-t cut, you should use a different algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Solving the global minimum cut by computing multiple maximum flows is possible but suboptimal. Using the fastest known algorithm (Orlin for sparse graphs and King-Rao-Tarjan for dense graphs), maxflow can be solved in O(mn). By picking a fixed source vertex and computing maxflow to all other vertices, we get (by the duality) the global mincut in O(mn²).

There exist several algorithms specifically for global mincuts. For algorithms independent of graph structure, the most commonly used are

- [Nagamochi & Ibaraki, 1992](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0405004), O(nm + n²log(n)). Does not use flows and gradually shrinks the graph.
- [Stoer & Wagner, 1997](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=263872), also O(nm + n²log(n)). Easier to implement. It is implemented in [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/stoer_wagner_min_cut.html)

Hao & Orlin's algorithm can also run very fast in practice, especially when some of the known heuristics are applied.

There are many algorithms that exploit structural properties of input graphs. I'd suggest the recent algorithm of [Brinkmeier, 2007](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00224-007-2010-2) which runs in "O(n² max(log(n), min(m/n,δ/ε))), where ε is the minimal edge weight, and δ is the minimal weighted degree". In particular, when we ignore the weights, we get O(n² log(n)) for inputs with m in o(n log(n)) and O(nm) for denser graphs, meaning its time complexity is never worse than that of N-I or S-W regardless of input.